# How to average over time in matlab fints time series object?

Tags: matlab

**Data**

Financial Time Series Object (FINTS) with the following columns:

Date     Time      Number

I have data for every hour for every single day for 2 years.

**Problem**

I want to have the average for every hour for the past year. In other words, I want to have the time column with all 24 hours in a day and the corresponding number should be an average of all the past days at that same hour.

**What I tried**

I've tried looking at the perav, tsmovavg function and accumarray function.  Any other ideas? I am new to Matlab so I don't even know how to loop over this time series data. There must be some sort of way to do this though considering the fact it is a time series object using time series specific functions.

Edit: I'd like to leave it in a time series ideally.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data has been stored in a Matrix `F`, "Date" is year and "Time" is hour, you can use this `for` loop to print average of the same time during different days of particular year `y`:

```
for t=unique(F(:,2))
   mean(F(F(:,2)==t & F(:,1)==y) ,3)
end
```

Explanation:
By using `unique` you can retrieve different values of "Time". Two conditions inside the `mean` make sure mean of the same "Time" in a particular year.

Comment: This isn't working. I said my data was specifically in a financial time series format. I tried converting it like this F = fts2mat(data, 1) and it loses the time component. Then I get the following error: Matrix dimensions must agree. mean(F(F(:,2)==t & F(:,1)==y) ,3)

Comment: what is the size of F? What is the size data?